# Cannot release build Flutter android

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-release

I want to build the release app of Flutter for both iOS and Android everything good and run very well on the development and iOS IPA release but not for android

I try to

**flutter build appbundle**

but I got this problem

> A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:uploadCrashlyticsMappingFileRelease' (type 'UploadMappingFileTask').

> File 'PROJECT_NAME/build/app/generated/res/google-services/release/values/values.xml' specified for property 'googleServicesFile' does not exist.

I already try to

- Invalidate caches and restart
- flutter clean

but nothing solve. any face this or any solution to suggest me?

Comment: Have you added `Firebase` to your project?

Comment: sure I'm already add it.

Comment: You completely went through all the steps that are described in the [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/installation/android) and added `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` ???

Comment: yes I  already add this to the gradle

Comment: Check again, I have a suspicion that you did something wrong, for example, added to the wrong gradle file. Or remove Firebase completely from the project and try to build

Answer (score 0):

firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.5.x will failed with recent Firebase dependencies...

I'm using this in `android/build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.7.1'
}
```